# Function not returning new data from updated table

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I uploaded new rows into a table via my editor (SQLyog).  The table already had data.  The table was also indexed prior to the upload.  After uploading the new data, when tasked to find the new data during testing, the code spits out the debug message, "No data" (see below), but it returns the pre-existing data just fine.  Additionally, MySQL queries in the editor will return the new data.

If it matters, the table is a MyISAM table.

What should I be doing to allow the code/function to return the new data?

Here is the snippet of code that returns the debug message:

```
            $code = $this->_addData($order_product['pid'],$order_product['qty'],$order_id);
            $order_product['code'] = $code;

            if(!$code) {

                $this->log->debug('No data');
```

I have a feeling the answer lay in something I've not done in uploading the data or done incorrectly there, as the code works perfectly to find the existing data.  Of course, I could be completely wrong.

EDIT:  Below is the addData function.  Obviously there are some additional function calls in there. Again, these all work fine for 'pre-existing' data in the table, but don't seem to find the 'new' rows of data.

```
protected function _addData($product_id,$quantity,$order_id){

    $this->load->model('checkout/data');

    if($this->model_checkout_data->productHasCampaign($product_id)){

        $this->_hasData = true;

        $codes = $this->model_checkout_data->checkAvailableData($product_id,$quantity);

        //if there is data, update them
        if(count($codes) == $quantity){
            foreach($codes as $code){
                $this->model_checkout_data->confirmCode($code['id'],$order_id);
            }
        } else {
            //Redirect to Cart
            $this->session->data['error_code'] = ERROR_OUT_OF_DATA;
            header('Location: index.php?checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        $this->model_checkout_data->updateProductQuantity($product_id);

        $this->_Data[$product_id] = $codes;

        return $codes;

    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: no idea, what `_addData(...)` does and where something is selected again.

Comment: After entering the data through SQLYog, if you check the table contents tab, is the data there? I ask because I have made the mistake before of entering data manually and not saving it.

Comment: You're adding not selecting, and where would `$order_product['code']` come from?

Comment: @Endacy , Thanks.  Yes, the data is in the table.  When I query the table via SQLyog with to return the new data, it is found.

Comment: @VolkerK  -addData is a function that gets the info.  If it would be helpful, I can post it, but does the fact that this code works fine to identify and return existing data (but not the new data) mean it's working correctly?

Comment: @AbraCadaver.  Thanks for the comment.  Can you clarify a little?

Comment: (You don't need to apologise for asking basic questions. As long as they are described well, people will be willing to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow!).

Comment: @ halfer - Many thanks!  Been lurking for a while as I try to get underneath different issues.  It's helped out tremendously already.

Comment: `. If it would be helpful, I can post it` - most likely yes, if it's not too long. `addData is a function that gets the info`- then this method should/would be called getData, no?

Comment: @VolkerK - I added the function into the main post.

Comment: That looks like a more or less complete framework. Does this thing have a name, lilke e.g. OpenCard? Unless you find someone who knows that framework I doubt it very much that anyone can help you beyond: install a debugger like e.g. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html

Comment: @VolkerK - Thanks.  It's custom code.  I guess, because it works just fine with pre-existing data, that I'm more interested to know if there is anything I could look at outside of the code - e.g. do i need to re-index the table?  Does something need to happen in the INNODB tables or the stats tables of the information schema to 'update' it with the new data?  Things like that...  Thanks!